# CSS Div Element with Inline-Block doesn't work

Tags: html, css

When using two div elements and the inline-block the two div's do not stand beside one another.

This is the code. (I configured some of the paragraphs and images to work better. I made sure the result was the same first though.)

```
<head>
    <style>
    #line {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:75%;
        border: 5px solid orange;
    }
    #TEST {
        width:100%;
    }
    #pTxt {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #heading {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="line">
            <div>
                <img id="TEST" alt="PICTURE" src="test.png" />
                <div id="pTxt">
                     <h3 id="heading">
                                HEADING
                            </h3>

                    <p>TEST</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>TEST</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="line">
            <img alt="PICTURE" id="TEST" src="test.png" />
            <div id="pTxt">
                 <h3 id="heading">
                                HEADING
                            </h3>

                <p>TEST</p>
                <br/>
                <p>TEST</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gqfmmdy9/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any reason behind `margin-right:75%;` try removing it

Comment: (1) `#TEST { width:auto; }` instead of `100%`. (2) Try smaller margin like `margin-right:5%;` instead of `75%` on `#line`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gqfmmdy9/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `margin-right: 75%`, which is pushing the next element to the bottom. You'll have to remove it.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/gqfmmdy9/6/)

```
#line {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5%;
    border: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```css
#line {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
#TEST {
  width: 100%;
}
#pTxt {
  text-align: center;
}
#heading {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <div>
    <img id="TEST" alt="PICTURE" src="test.png" />
    <div id="pTxt">
      <h3 id="heading">
                        HEADING
                    </h3>
      <p>
        TEST
      </p>
      <br/>
      <p>
        TEST
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="line">
  <img alt="PICTURE" id="TEST" src="test.png" />
  <div id="pTxt">
    <h3 id="heading">
                        HEADING
                    </h3>
    <p>
      TEST
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
      TEST
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work for me, but for some reason there is a problem with the border. The border seems to be blocking the next div. I know this because the 2nd div same line as the first div when I zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#line {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-left:5%;

        margin-right:75%;

        border: 5px solid orange;
}
```

Your styles *are* working.

Try swapping `margin-right:75%;` for `margin-right:2%;`.

EDIT: Also, I suspect you need to give `#line` an explicit width declaration. Something like  `width:12%;`.

Comment: The border is now going to the end of the page, blocking out the 2nd div.

Comment: Have you given #line an explicit width declaration?

Answer (score -1):

If you want both the `div`s side by side, you can use `<table>` tag. See if this works for you.

```
<table>
    <tr><td><div class="line">
            <div>
                <img class="TEST" alt="PICTURE" src="test.png"/>
                <div class="pTxt">
                    <h3 class="heading">
                        HEADING
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        TEST
                    </p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>
                        TEST
                    </p>
                </div>
           </div>
    </div></td>
<td><div class="line">
        <img alt="PICTURE" class="TEST" src="test.png"/>
                <div class="pTxt">
                    <h3 class="heading">
                        HEADING
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        TEST
                    </p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>
                        TEST
                    </p>
                </div>
    </div></td></tr>
</table>
```

and CSS

```
.line {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:75%;
        border: 5px solid orange;
}
.TEST {
    width:100%;
}
.pTxt {
    text-align:center;
}
.heading {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: It sorta works for me, the p tags seem to be elongating the div making the border farther to the right.

Comment: using tables for layout is a no no.